# web.xml the markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: java, xml, markup, well-formed

I'm trying to set up DWR, direct web remoting, and they had me put in the web.xml this piece of code here,

```
<servlet>
  <display-name>DWR Servlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>  
  <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
     <param-name>debug</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

but I get the error the markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed, and it is at the servlet-mapping part. I tried putting the servlet mapping inside of servlet and it got rid of the error but the webpage `http://localhost:8081/WebProject01/dwr/`  still wouldn't come up. The dwr.xml didn't have any errors so that looked good. Is there another way to fix the error message?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: That fragment looks ok and it validates with the [3.0 spec schema definition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/web_xml.htm#CIHFAIDA). Make sure you have such a namespace definition and schema location in your `web.xml`, it would ahve warned you when you put `servlet-mapping` inside of `servlet`. Please post the whole web.xml  for further help.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<servlet>
  <display-name>DWR Servlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>  
  <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
     <param-name>debug</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Comment: thanks for the reply @A4L. I changed it to this,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<servlet>
  <display-name>DWR Servlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>  
  <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
     <param-name>debug</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
</servlet>
and now there is a warning at the top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<servlet>
    <display-name>DWR Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

is not a valid `web.xml` (this is not even valid XML)

The root element of a web.xml is `web-app`. Please refer to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/web_xml.htm) to understand how a web deployment descriptor should look like and what it is for.

You could edit you web xml in this way:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <display-name>DWR Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

`version="3.0"` must be support supported by your application server (for example tomcat 7.x) Otherwise pleas look for the corresponding declarations for the servlet spec your app-server implements, [for example for 2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/webapp/web_xml.html)

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
```

Comment: I put that in and now it works. Thanks for the help!